# Did early biblical figures like Isaac abstain from intimate relations until marriage?

Tags: marriage, avot-patriarch-fathers, sexuality, shidduchim-dating

In biblical accounts, several figures, such as Isaac, are noted to have married at a relatively older age compared to today's standards. Isaac, for instance, married at the age of 40. Given the societal norms and the cultural backdrop of those times:

Is there any indication or evidence in traditional sources that figures like Isaac abstained from intimate relations until they were officially married? Were there any mentions or implications about their relationships or interactions with women prior to their recorded marriages? How did societal norms of their times view celibacy or waiting until marriage for intimate relations?

Comment: I imagine this question could be answered with some biblical figures (as has been proven already in the answers with Jacob), but I don’t think there’s an all-inclusive answer. I’d imagine most sources are silent on such matters, as there really isn’t a good way to know, since the Torah does not tell us or even hint to relationships outside of their marriages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keep in mind that the Rambam (Ishus 1:1) states that before the giving of the Torah marriage was simply an act of intimacy with intent to marry. No formal ceremony. So your question is basically, "Were the patriarchs engaging in recreational sex." I do feel like I have to say that the early biblical figures were paragons of moral virtue.

That being said, in I think there are two proofs to your question (besides the midrash about Yaakov others quoted.)
First, the medrash (quoted in Rashi to Genesis 37:2) says that among the accusations Joseph accused his brothers of was a claim of having relations with the local girls.
Second, the incident with Yehuda and Tamar.

Putting these two together you get a picture that an accusation of a casual sexual relationship was considered to be a vicious slander, but under the right circumstances it wasn't something they viewed as forbidden.

(Generally, the nefesh hachaim says the avos kept the mitzvos but since it was pre-Torah if they saw the ratzon Hashem conflicted with the mitzvos of the Torah they would follow the ratzon Hashem.)

Answer (score 9):

I don't know the source off the top of my head, but I recall seeing a source (maybe a midrash) that says that when Yaakov conceived Reuvain not only was that his first time ever having intercourse it was the first time in his life he had ever had a seminal emmission. I believe he was in his 50s or 60s?

Comment: Here's the alley-oop: [Gen. Rabbah 98:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereshit_Rabbah.98.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Comment: He was 84. And yes it was his first Emission. The pasuk says ראשית אוני. The number 84 is not random. According to the Ari zal one has to fast 84 times to be metaken zera levatala. Yaakov came to be metaken the Part of Adam that sinned sexually.

Comment: @Deuteronomy _swish_ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/137150/31534

Comment: But it doesn't say this about Yitzchak. Or Moshe. Or lots of other greats. Seemingly this was unique to Yaakov and not relevant to the general question.

Comment: @DoubleAA that doesn't follow at all. What was unique to Yaakov was that he named a son with that intention. Other greats named their firstborns for other traits. (Besides, Yitzchak had twins, so even if he wanted to, that name wouldn't have been possible, since logically it would be equally applicable to both, and it would be weird to name them both the same thing.) The answer is on point.

Comment: @Ethan You have no basis to extrapolate from Yaakov to anyone else.

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree, which is why I argued with your comment. You extrapolated that this standard was unique to Yaakov and that therefore other greats were not so observant of shmiras habris. That doesn't necessarily follow. Now in reality, the answer still is relevant to the question, because it demonstrates that this was a value at the time, since it's reasonable to say that Yaakov would have learned his values from his father and grandfather, and would have taught them. Since the question was about examples of this value, a demonstration of it is unquestionably relevant.

Comment: @EthanLeonard I don't think you know what extrapolate means.

Answer (score 5):

The pasuk says:

Genesis 49:3

***רְאוּבֵן֙ בְּכֹ֣רִי אַ֔תָּה כֹּחִ֖י וְרֵאשִׁ֣ית אוֹנִ֑י יֶ֥תֶר שְׂאֵ֖ת וְיֶ֥תֶר עָֽז׃
Reuben, you are my first-born,
My might and first fruit of my vigor,
Exceeding in rank
And exceeding in honor.***

Rashi comments, quoting from Genesis Rabbah 98:

**THE BEGINNING OF MY VIGOR — That is the first drop [of semen] (טִפָּה רִאשׁוֹנָה)
as he had not experienced a seminal emission from all of his days [until that time] (Genesis Rabbah 98:4)**

The wordinh "טִפָּה רִאשׁוֹנָה" indicated that he never had Sex before, never masturbated before and never saw an emission of semen.

The Pasuk speaks about Jacob, but Jacob was 84 when he married Leah while Isaac was between 40-60 when he first married/had relations with Rivkah. So KalVaChomer to your question.

Comment: But it doesn't say this about Yitzchak. Or Moshe. Or lots of other greats. Seemingly this was unique to Yaakov and not relevant to the general question.

Comment: @DoubleAA that doesn't follow at all. What was unique to Yaakov was that he named a son with that intention. Other greats named their firstborns for other traits. (Besides, Yitzchak had twins, so even if he wanted to, that name wouldn't have been possible, since logically it would be equally applicable to both, and it would be weird to name them both the same thing.) The answer is on point.

Comment: @Ethan surely it's logically possible that everyone had this and Yaakov decided to name after a common thing. That doesn't sound very reasonable though. It would be like me naming my child "bipedal" to thank God for him having two legs.

Comment: @DoubleAA it would be strange for me to suggest that without evidence, except that we know it happened. Esav was named for his hair, Yaakov for his actions during birth.

Comment: @EthanLeonard Yaakov's action during birth was unique! Esav's hair was unique!

Comment: @DoubleAA No, they are common with respect to the Reuven situation, and at face value are much less logical and meaningful choices. (Of course, if you believe in נבואה קטנה with respect to naming, or that other values are hidden within seemingly shallow names, then there's no reason to suggest that pointing out shmiras habris is of utmost importance.) Your argument is essentially that if you didn't name your firstborn after "reishis ono", you were not shomer habris. Doesn't hold water if you ask me. Besides, Yaakov married much older than prior forefathers, and had lived with Lavan for years.

Comment: @DoubleAA besides, the statement that Reuven was "reishis ono" is more than just suggesting shmiras habris. It also suggests that Leah became pregnant immediately, from the first time. If that did not happen by others, it would not make sense to give that name.